# Adding scripts to admin page in my theme

Tags: admin, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

In functions.php of my theme I have code to add page in admin area and append scripts to it. But scripts are not loaded. Bellow is code. Commented out add_action lines are the one I did check.

```
    // functions.php
    // Append user style and scripts to Add New Wallpaper menu
    function pb_admin_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
      wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
      wp_register_script('pb-upload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pb-upload.js');
      wp_enqueue_script('pb-upload');
    }

    function pb_admin_style() {
      wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    }


    function pb_wallpaper_adminmenu() {
      $page = add_menu_page('Dodaj Tapetę', 'Dodaj Tapetę', 'edit_posts', 'add-wallpaper', 'pb_add_wallpaper', '', 6);
    }
    //  add_action( 'admin_head-add-wallpaper', 'pb_admin_scripts');
    //  add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-add-wallpaper', 'pb_admin_scripts');
    //  add_action( 'admin_print_styles-add-wallpaper', 'pb_admin_style');
    //  add_action( 'load-add-wallpaper', 'pb_admin_scripts');
    //  add_action( 'load-add-wallpaper', 'pb_admin_style');


    // add new wallpaper
    function pb_add_wallpaper() {
      ?>
    <div class="wallpaper-add">
      <h3>Dodaj Nową Tapetę</h3>
      <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pb_add_wallpaper" />
        <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        <input type="hidden" name="upload_image" id="upload_image" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field('pb_add_wallpaper', '_nonce'); ?>
      </form>
    </div>

    <?php
    } 

    add_action('admin_menu', 'pb_wallpaper_adminmenu');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pb_admin_style');` and as the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) states, the `admin_enqueue_scripts` can also be used to target a specific admin page. Use this to only select the admin page you want.

```
function pb_admin_style($hook) {
    if( 'edit.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('/myscript.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pb_admin_style' );
```

Comment: It did work but my script is loaded on every page and that is not that what I want

Comment: `admin_enqueue_scripts` passes a variable with the current hook name. Use this to only select the admin page you want. `echo` or `var_dump` to see what string is passed to your specific page. (`pb_admin_style($hook)`).

Comment: Sometimes you just have to read the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: @hampusn Did as you siad. Checked with vardump what value is hidden in $hook and added `if( 'toplevel_page_add-wallpaper' != $hook) return;`

Comment: @Miha Could you please edit your answer to include a working example with the hook condition aswell? It will be more useful to others who find this later.

Comment: @hampusn done it

Answer (score 0):

This is my load script method , as this i load scripts in specific post type this example is for post_type='resources'

```
if(!function_exists('load_pdf_uploader_scripts'))
{
    function load_pdf_uploader_scripts($hook)
    {
        //Check if is in edit post
        if(isset($_GET['post']) && isset($_GET['action']))
        {
            //Get post type
            $post_type = get_post_type( $_GET['post'] );

            //Check if we are in resources post type to load specific scripts
            if($post_type == 'resources' && $_GET['action']=='edit')
            {
                //Load the script
                wp_enqueue_script('pdfupload', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/pdfupload.js', array('jquery')); // in footer
            }
        }
        //Check if is new post item
        elseif(isset($_GET['post_type']))
        {
            //Check if we are in resources post type to load specific scripts
            if($_GET['post_type'] == 'resources')
            {
                //Load the script
                wp_enqueue_script('pdfupload', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/pdfupload.js', array('jquery')); // in footer
            }
        }
    }
    //We load this script only in admin area
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_pdf_uploader_scripts');
}
```