# wp_enqueue_scripts does not work on admin page

Tags: shortcode, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to create a slider shortcode with [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and for some reason it does not work in the admin page in the page builder and I'm getting this error: [image]

I already enqueue it in my `functions.php` like so:

```
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js',array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

And added

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

In my shortcode function but still doesn't work, though the enqueued style and script is visible on the page already.

Note: It works fine in the front end. I just wanted to show it in the admin page so my client can see it while updating the page with page builder.

Comment: You should use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) action hook. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67476/adding-scripts-to-admin-page-in-my-theme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding scripts to admin page in my theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67476/adding-scripts-to-admin-page-in-my-theme)

Comment: @cjbj unfortunately no, please see https://share.getcloudapp.com/NQuJpeXm

Answer (score 0):

Could your shortcode function be running or loading before Slick.js has loaded?

Simple solution might be to load slick in the header by changing the last parameter from true to false, but this isn't really the 'correct' way as it will impact performance slightly.

If your shortcode function is in a seperate file loaded by enqueueing then add slick as a dependancy.

If it's in the HTML so loaded from a PHP file, move it to a seperate JS file, enqueue it with admin_enqueue_scripts and again add Slick as a dependency.

Comment: I moved it to a seperate JS file and I got rid of the erorr but still doesn't work. 
https://share.getcloudapp.com/YEuX4do1 I already set `$(window).load`